# C++ pool allocator vs static allocation , cache performance

Tags: c++, caching, memory-management

Given that I have two parallel and identically sized arrays of the following structs:

```
    struct Matrix
    {
        float data[16];
    };

    struct Vec4
    {
        float data[4];
    }

    //Matrix arrM[256];  //for illustration
    //Vec4 arrV[256];
```

Lets say I wish to iterate over the two arrays sequentially as fast as possible.  Lets say the function is something like:

```
for (int i=0; i < 256; ++i)
{
    readonlyfunc(arrMPtr[i].data);
    readonlyfunc(arrVPtr[i].data
}
```

Assuming that my allocations are aligned for each array, both in the case of statically allocated or heap memory. Assuming that my cache line size 64 bytes.

**Would I achieve the same cache locality and performance if I were to store my data as**:

A)

```
//aligned
 static Matrix arrM[256];
 static Vec4 arrV[256];

 Matrix* arrMPtr = arrM[0];
 Vec4* arrVPtr = arrV[0];
```

vs

B)

```
//aligned
char* ptr = (char*) malloc(256*sizeof(Matrix)+256*sizeof(Vec4));

Matrix* arrMPtr = (Matrix*) ptr;
Vec4* arrVPtr = (Vec4*) ptr+256*sizeof(Matrix);
```

Comment: Likely there is no difference, both (statically or dynamically memory) will be accessed the same way (through a pointer)

Comment: Will the the two static arrays be contiguous though relative to each other?  What about the order, does it matter?

Comment: it's not the quite the same for *single* access, though for a loop like that I doubt there's going to be measureable difference.

Comment: @skimon: they can be "arbitrary" allocated, so no, you cannot assume they are contiguous (and I don't see why that would *matter*). what do you mean by order?

Comment: It's impossible to say without knowing more about what your doing.  Keep in mind that static arrays will likely already be in the L1 cache (in your case 256 matrices and vectors will fit in the 32kb cache) whereas arrays allocated from the heap will have to be read into the L1 cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How the memory is allocated (heap or statically allocated) makes no difference to the memory's ability to be cached. Since both of these data structures are fairly large (1024 and 4096 bytes, respectively), the exact alignment of the first and last elements probably doesn't matter either (but it does matter if you are using SSE instructions to access the content!).

Whether the memory is close together or not won't make a huge difference, as long as the allocation is small enough to easily fit in the cache, but big enough to take up multiple cache-lines.

You may find that using a structure with 20 float values works out better, if you are working sequentially through both arrays. But that only works if you don't ever need to do other things with the data where having a single array makes more sense.

There may be a difference in the compiler's ability to translate the code to avoid an extra memory access. This will clearly depend on the actual code (e.g. will the compiler inline function containing the for-loop, does it inline the `readonlyfunc` code, etc, etc. If so, the static allocation can be translated from the pointer variant (which loads the address of the pointer to get the address of the data) into a constant address calculation. It probably doesn't make a huge difference in such a large loop as this.

Always, when it comes to performance, sometimes small things can make big differences, so if this is really important, do some experiments, using YOUR compiler, YOUR actual code. We can only give relatively speculative advice, based on our experience. Different compilers do different things with the same code, different processors do different things with the same machine code (both different actual architectures (whether it's instruction set architecture ARM vs X86, or implementation of the architecture such as AMD Opteron vs Intel Atom or ARM Cortex A15 vs Cortex M3). Memory configurations on your particular system will also affect things, how big caches are, etc, etc.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed answer.  My understanding is that what will be pulled into the cache will be the line/ lines immediately after what we accessed.  If the static allocations are not adjacent in memory im not sure that that would work.  Whereas in the malloc example the allocation is perfectly adjacent ( at least in virtual memory ).  Come to think of it does the cache use the physical address of memory locations to decide what is evicted - if so is all of this excercise pointless unless the memory is truly contiguous in physical memory?

Comment: That's not what I meant. I mean that there is no difference - all arrays, whether allocated with malloc or as static array declarations, will be contiguous areas of memory for each array (in virtual space - may or may not be contiguous in physical space). Caches typically work on the physical address (thus not having to clear the entire cache if another process gets switched in), but a block of memory in physical memory is still at least 4KB in any reasonably modern machine. Again, benchmark your system, compare the two solutions, see if you notice any difference. I suspect not.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say without knowning more about what your doing and testing.  It might be more efficient to use a struct of arrays.

```
struct MatrixVec
{
    float m[16];
    float v[4];
};
```

One important point is that malloc allocates memory from the heap whereas static arrays are allocated on the stack.  The stack is already likely in the L1 cache whereas the memory from the heap will have to be read in.  Instead you can try a less known function for dynamic memory allocation called `alloca` which allocates memory on the stack.  In your case you could try

```
char* ptr = (char*) alloca(256*sizeof(Matrix)+256*sizeof(Vec4))
```

See Agner Fog's [Optimizing software in C++](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf).  See the section "9.6 Dynamic memory allocation".  Here are the advantages he lists for `alloca` compared to `malloc`

- There is very little overhead to the allocation process because the microprocessor
  has hardware support for the stack.
- The memory space never becomes fragmented thanks to the first-in-last-out nature
  of the stack.
- Deallocation has no cost because it goes automatically when the function returns.
  There is no need for garbage collection.
- The allocated memory is contiguous with other objects on the stack, which makes
  data caching very efficient.